# Magento 1.4.0.1 and SOAP/REST

Tags: api, soap, rest-api

When I run this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/store/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl
```

I get this returned:

```
0 Unable to load Soap extension on the server
```

How do I enable it? I also don't understand where to get the key's used for the logins.

Is the REST api avail on the version I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Seems there is no SOAP extension in your PHP config enabled.

Your server might not be compatible with Magento, try this script: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

2.) The login can be set up in the magento backend: System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC - Users and System > Web Services > SOAP/XML-RPC - Roles

3.) No, the Magento REST API was introduced in Magento 1.7.

Comment: Ran magento-check and it confirmed OK. `Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.

You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
Safe Mode is off
You have MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
You have the curl extension
You have the dom extension
You have the gd extension
You have the hash extension
You have the iconv extension
You have the mcrypt extension
You have the pcre extension
You have the pdo extension
You have the pdo_mysql extension
You have the simplexml extension`    Looking at the source, it DOES NOT check for SOAP.

Comment: Sorry then, i thought the SOAP check is in. You can just create a file and call phpinfo() and check if/what infos are present about SOAP.

Comment: No SOAP in PHP when running phpinfo().

Comment: Disregard as we are going to leave it alone for now. I have to have my admin install some other apache modules so I will also ask him to install SOAP.